# run some code each time heroku deployment occur

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I want to put some code that will run every time I publish my app on heroku,
where should I put it? I need access to my models to run it.

Comment: Probably the capistrano deployment file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it running every time you spin up a dyno (scale, restart,env change, or push) then use a .profile file (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#startup). If you want to have it only run when you do a deploy use a http deploy hook https://addons.heroku.com/deployhooks that hits another application that does the work you want.